# Combination of tkinter askopenfilename and askdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, user-experience

The script I'm currently working on requires the user to select files.

The files are in folders in numbers from a few up to couple of hundreds.
The current version of the script does uses `askdirectory` so the user selects a folder an all the needed files in the folder with the right file type are processed.

This does work for most cases but if a user wants to only process a certain amount of files in a folder (to save time) he/she needs to create a separate folder and copy the files over (which does take time).

**Question:**
*Is there a function to be able to select either a folder or files?*

- The script cannot have a GUI for the user to click a button to choose
  if he/she wants to select files or a folder.

Comment: How do you determine which certain files to be selected?

Comment: Currently all the files from inside the folder are put into a list and the script works trough the list processing a file if the file type is right.

for files in os.walk(folder_path):
if ".filetype" in files: dostuff()

Comment: Take a look on `glob.glob(...)`.

Comment: @GittingGud: Use [ttk.Treeview](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html), but it's not a ready to use `dialog`. Try [dirbrowser.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Demo/tkinter/ttk/)

Comment: you will have to create GUI for this. It is only window with two buttons. Nothing more. Or you can run script with parameter in terminal which open askdirectory or askopenfilename - but probably this is not good solution for you. Finally you can create two scripts - one with askdirectory and one with askopenfilename and run it separatelly.